# MySQL Show Required Class Completed

Tags: mysql, sql

//UPDATE: the answer provided worked but I ran into another situation. If a student moves to another position, they need to keep the credit from the completion of the previous position when there is an overlap. See situation below:

I have 2 courses, courseA and courseB that are required for each of the two trainingcodes. If a student takes courseA and courseB under training code 10, then moves to a new position (training code 30), they are showing an exception as not completing CourseA and CourseB because their code changed. Even though the course is the same. I have tried comparing the count of description but it isn't working. The course name is activityId on the training table as well as the require training table from above. Any thoughts? Thanks

I am trying to write a MySql script to determine when a student completes or has not completed all classes from a list of required training (Curriculum). 
In the example below, I need to show that John Doe has completed class 1,2,and 3 for traininglevel 0. I also need to show that Jane Does has not
completed all classes as class 2 is missing. I have tried to assign an ordernumber to the classes, so if you get to ordernum 3 (Class3) you are 
complete, but I am missing gaps if the student didn't take class 2. Also this need to run through 1500 students to show who has / has not fulfilled 
Level 0 training.

`tbltraining`

```
firstname
lastname
email
organization
activity
description
status
jobcode
```

Ex tbltraining

```
John    |   Doe     |   jdoe@email.com  |   1233    |   Class1      |   Certification   |   Completed   |   030 
John    |   Doe     |   jdoe@email.com  |   1233    |   Class2      |   Certification   |   Completed   |   030 
John    |   Doe     |   jdoe@email.com  |   1233    |   Class3      |   Certification   |   Completed   |   030 
John    |   Doe     |   jdoe@email.com  |   1233    |   OtherClass  |   Certification   |   Completed   |   030 
John    |   Doe     |   jdoe@email.com  |   1233    |   OtherClass2 |   Certification   |   Completed   |   030 
Jane    |   Doe     |   jadoe@email.com |   3311    |   Class1      |   Certification   |   Completed   |   010 
Jane    |   Doe     |   jadoe@email.com |   3311    |   Class3      |   Certification   |   Completed   |   010 
James   |   Doe     |   jmdoe@email.com |   1233    |   Class1      |   Certification   |   Completed   |   030 
James   |   Doe     |   jmdoe@email.com |   1233    |   Class2      |   Certification   |   Incomplete  |   030
```

`tblreqtraining`

```
trainingname
trainingdescription
trainingcode
traininglevel
```

Ex tblreqtraining

```
Class1  |   Certification   |   30  |   0
Class2  |   Certification   |   30  |   0
Class3  |   Certification   |   30  |   0
Class1  |   Certification   |   10  |   0
Class2  |   Certification   |   10  |   0
Class3  |   Certification   |   10  |   0
Class4  |   Certification   |   10  |   0
```

- `Activity` needs to match `trainingname`
- `Description` needs to match `trainingdescription`
- `jobcode` needs to match `trainingcode`

Query:

```
SELECT tra.firstname, tra.lastname, tra.email, tra.organization, tra.activity, tra.description, 
        tra.jobcode, req.trainingname, req.traininglevel, req.trainingcode
FROM tbltraining tra
RIGHT JOIN tblreqtraining req on tra.activity = req.trainingname and right(tra.jobcode, 2) = req.trainingcode
WHERE (right(tra.jobcode,2) = '30' or right(tra.jobcode,2) = '10')
and tra.description = 'Certification'
and tra.status = 'Completed'
and req.traininglevel = 0
```

Any thoughts or direction on this would be appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear what the results would look like.

Comment: I would be able to pul a query to show a list of all students that have not completed the level 0 curriculum. Name,email,job code, organization. Or a list of the same columns that have completed The level 0 curriculum.

Comment: When you use `RIGHT JOIN` you shouldn't have conditions on the left table in the `WHERE` clause, they should be in the `ON` clause. Otherwise you;ll filter out all the `NULL` values from non-matching rows, and it's like `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the count of classes for each training code, and the count of classes that each student has completed for each training code. If the student's count is not the same as the class's count, they didn't complete all the classes.

```
SELECT tra.firstname, tra.lastname, tra.trainingcode,
        CASE IFNULL(tra.completed_count, 0)
            WHEN req.class_count THEN 'Completed All'
            ELSE 'Not completed'
        END
FROM (
    SELECT trainingcode, COUNT(*) class_count
    FROM tblreqtraining
    WHERE traininglevel = 0
    GROUP BY trainingcode
) AS req
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT firstname, lastname, RIGHT(jobcode, 2) AS trainingcode, COUNT(*) AS completed_count
    FROM tbltraining AS tra
    JOIN tblreqtraining AS req ON RIGHT(tra.jobcode, 2) = req.trainingcode AND tra.activity = req.trainingname
    WHERE tra.description = 'Certification' AND tra.status = 'Completed'
    AND req.traininglevel = 0
    GROUP BY firstname, lastname, trainingcode
) AS tra ON tra.trainingcode = req.trainingcode
```

Comment: Yes, that is starting to work! But in the LEFT JOIN with the tbltraining, all completed certifications are being counted including certifications not included in the level 0 curriculum. I am trying to add the following to the WHERE statement in the LEFT JOIN: 

WHERE description = 'Certification' AND status = 'Completed' and activity in (SELECT trainingname FROM tblreqtraining WHERE traininglevel = '0')

to only count the number of completed courses with the name in tblreqtraining. 

Also think i need a DISTINCT somewhere as students are completing the course more than one.

Comment: Just add `AND traininglevel = 0` to the `tbltraining` subquery.

Comment: I've added a join to the second subquery so it only counts classes that are in `tblreqtraining`.

Comment: Just for an added bonus. Say a student with jobcode 010 takes class1 (from example above) but moves to a new jobcode 030 and takes class2 and class3. Even though class1 is the same for both jobcodes, the student doesn’t get credit for class1 because it was under a different jobcode. Thoughts?

Comment: I haven't figured out the whole query, but it probably involves comparing `COUNT(DISTINCT trainingname)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT description)` after joining the two tables. BTW, you really need to normalize your schema, you shouldn't be repeating student details like email and organization in the training table, it should just have a foreign key to the employee table.

Comment: I am going to try the count distinct on name and description. I agree with the normalization. Email is FK to the employee table. The training data I receive just includes name and organization.

Comment: I have 2 courses, courseA and courseB that are required for each of the two trainingcodes. if a student takes courseA and courseB under training code 10, then moves to a new position (training code 30), they are showing an exception as not completing CourseA and CourseB because their code changed. Even through the course is the same. I have tried comparing the count of description but it isn't working. The course name is activityId on the training table as well as the require training table from above. Any other thoughts? Thanks